# implementing language in mobile

Tags: internationalization

i want to implement english language for all regions like africa,america,uk and china.I have my language engine ready and its working fine ,i just wanted to know what are difference between english spoken in US,UK ,China and other countries.Is it merely phonetic diffrence or there are differences in their characters set also.

Comment: US to UK: String.Replace('z','s'); Problem solved. :)

Comment: @George and for other versions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are only three official versions of English: UK (the original), US (what most people refer to when they say "English") and Canadian.

Usually, it's enough when you support US English; that is understood by everyone.

When software developers say "internationalization" (or i18n), they usually mean to translate the US English texts into the local language (Chinese, Arabic, Hindi, German, French, etc). So you should consider this approach instead of supporting 3 versions of English.

Comment: my question is may be i write study as "study" ,in some other country in english itself it is written as "studi" so i have to reflect changes according to region ..

Comment: As I said: there are only three official dialects. There is no dictionary with "Chinese English"; there are English slangs which Chinese people use but they change by city district, not by country.